# How to getGenerated id from parent table and insert into child table

Tags: java, oracle

```
 try {

    currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();

        psParent=currentCon.prepareStatement("insert into accommodation (type,name,price,description,username)values(?,?,?,?,?)", PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        psParent.setString(1,type);
        psParent.setString(2,name);
        psParent.setFloat(3,price);
        psParent.setString(4,username);
        psParent.executeUpdate();

        accid= 0;
            rs = psParent.getGeneratedKeys();
            if (rs.next())
                accid = rs.getInt(1);

            rs.close();
            psParent.close();

        psChild=currentCon.prepareStatement("insert into room (accid, bed)values(?,?)");
        psChild.setInt(1,accid);
        psParent.setString(2,bed);
        psChild.executeUpdate();    }
```

after I run this, I got this error message : failed: An Exception has occurred! java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: internal error

Is there's something wrong with the code? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage of `getGenereatedKeys()` actually looks correct to me for Oracle, but the problem is actually with your first insert statement.  You have placeholders (and column names) for 5 columns, but you only bind 4 values.  Try something like this:

```
String sql = "insert into accommodation (type, name, price, description, username) ";
sql += "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
String generatedColumns[] = { "ID" };
psParent = currentCon.prepareStatement(sql, generatedColumns);
psParent.setString(1, type);
psParent.setString(2, name);
psParent.setFloat(3, price);
psParent.setString(4, description);   // I ADDED THIS LINE
psParent.setString(5, username);
psParent.executeUpdate();
```

I am assuming that you have a variable containing a description to be inserted.  If not, then remove `description` and its placeholder from the prepared statement entirely, or just insert null.

Comment: Thank you sir! But after I correct it, I got another message that say:  java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: getInt not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CRowidAccessor. Something wrong with accid = rs.getInt(1); ?

Comment: Can you tell me the exact line of code which is throwing this error?  Maybe your particular driver doesn't support `getGeneratedKeys`.  Without seeing your code, I can't give you an exact answer.

Comment: accid= 0;
            rs = psParent.getGeneratedKeys();
            if (rs.next())
                accid = rs.getInt(1);

            rs.close();
            psParent.close();

Comment: mine was : oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver. It's okay Sir! Thank you for answering :D

Comment: @fatinamirah Check my updated answer, paying close attention to the change: `psParent = currentCon.prepareStatement(sql, generatedColumns);`, where `generatedColumns` is a string array.  This should work.